# Override method using runtime library

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, runtime, objective-c-runtime

I need to override `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated`for all ViewControllers adding `NSLog(@"blabla")` in this method. I.e. after every call of viewWillAppear invokes implemented early realization of viewWillAppear + my NSLog message. Is it possible? If yes, please give me  an advice.

Currently I have tried this code

```
@implementation RuntimeTest

IMP previusImp;
IMP newIMP;
- (void)ovverrideViewWillAppearInViewController:(Class)vcClass {
    newIMP = class_getMethodImplementation([self class], @selector(viewWillAppear:));
    Method viewWillAppearMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(vcClass, @selector(viewWillAppear:));
    previusImp = method_setImplementation(viewWillAppearMethod, newIMP);
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    previusImp(self, @selector(viewWillAppear:), animated);
    NSLog(@"log2");
}

@end
```

then I have

```
@implementation IRViewController2

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"log");
}

@end
```

My custom `viewWillAppear` invokes first, then `viewWillAppear` from `IRViewController2`. And after this my  application crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS. What's wrong?

Comment: Yes You Can https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Perhaps I put it unclear. See updated question, please.

Comment: You should probably post your crash log, or at least part of it.

Comment: Unfortunately, crash log is clear.

Comment: create a custom view controller method from witch all the other controllers in your app inherit from, when you call super viewwillappear the viewdidappear from the parent method will get called before the viewdidappear from your child controller just add a super inside the parent method as well

Answer (score 2):

if you can't use a subclass because you want to do it globally, but also don't want to lose the old version of the method (so category override is out of the question) then you need to [swizzle away](http://cocoadev.com/wiki/MethodSwizzling) the old method, put in your new method that then calls the old method... I have used something called [JRSwizzle](https://github.com/rentzsch/jrswizzle) to perform this in the past, it makes it easy to swizzle without writing a bunch of runtime code.

```
if (![self jr_swizzleMethod:@selector(originalInit) withMethod:@selector(init) error:&err])
{
    NSLog(@"unable to jr_swizzle methods, error: %@",err);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
if (![self jr_swizzleMethod:@selector(init) withMethod:@selector(myInit) error:&err])
{
    NSLog(@"unable to jr_swizzle methods, error: %@",err);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

then your `-myInit` method can call `-originalInit` or whatever methods you are using.

Comment: You *can* do that and it is great for debugging, but don't do that in production code, please!

Comment: @bbum not that I have or would... but is there a hard and fast rule as to why you wouldn't ever want to do that in prod code? I mean as long as the old version gets used... maybe some methods relying on checking _cmd would get whacked?

Comment: Because -- even when calling the original implementation -- you are modifying the implementation details of a system framework.   Not only is this verboten in the app store (IIRC), it is fragile and will lead to maintenance headaches.   In particular, you are counting on the internal behavior to remain whatever constant you think you've observed.   Any software update can easily break your code.   Apple tests binary compatibility quite carefully against the API, but cannot test for modifications like this.